# autolisp read json object

Tags: json, autolisp

I have such a CAD multi-segment graphic data JSON object.
Sample example:

```json
{
 "type": "polyline",
 "points": [
   {
     "type": "arc",
     "center": {
       "x": -763.17,
       "y": -240.97
     },
     "radius": 6.5,
     "start_angle": -90,
     "end_angle": 0
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": 35,
     "y": -26
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": 35,
     "y": 26
   },
   {
     "type": "arc",
     "center": {
       "x": -673.17,
       "y": -150.97
     },
     "radius": 6.5,
     "start_angle": 0,
     "end_angle": 90
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": 28.5,
     "y": 32.5
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": -28.5,
     "y": 32.5
   },
   {
     "type": "arc",
     "center": {
       "x": -583.17,
       "y": -60.97
     },
     "radius": 6.5,
     "start_angle": 90,
     "end_angle": 180
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": -35,
     "y": 26
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": -35,
     "y": -26
   },
   {
     "type": "arc",
     "center": {
       "x": -493.17,
       "y": 29.03
     },
     "radius": 6.5,
     "start_angle": 180,
     "end_angle": -90
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": -28.5,
     "y": -32.5
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": -23.25,
     "y": -32.5
   },
   {
     "type": "arc",
     "center": {
       "x": -763.17,
       "y": -240.97
     },
     "radius": 6.5,
     "start_angle": -90,
     "end_angle": -1.6
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": -16.75,
     "y": -26.18
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": -16.09,
     "y": -2.8
   },
   {
     "type": "arc",
     "center": {
       "x": -584.77,
       "y": -62.57
     },
     "radius": 2,
     "start_angle": 88.4,
     "end_angle": 178.4
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": -14.04,
     "y": -0.86
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": 4.98,
     "y": -1.39
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": 4.98,
     "y": -1.39
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": 4.87,
     "y": -5.39
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": 4.87,
     "y": -5.39
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": -3.66,
     "y": -5.15
   },
   {
     "type": "arc",
     "center": {
       "x": -584.77,
       "y": -62.57
     },
     "radius": 6.5,
     "start_angle": 88.4,
     "end_angle": 178.4
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": -10.33,
     "y": -11.47
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": -10.74,
     "y": -25.82
   },
   {
     "type": "arc",
     "center": {
       "x": -494.77,
       "y": 27.43
     },
     "radius": 6.5,
     "start_angle": 178.4,
     "end_angle": -90
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": -4.24,
     "y": -32.5
   },
   {
     "type": "line",
     "x": 28.5,
     "y": -32.5
   }
 ],
 "isClosed": true,
 "hasArc": true
}
```

Can you write an Autolisp code that can be loaded into CAD to generate this graphic with just one click?

I asked chatgpt and it said like that :

```
lisp
(defun c:JSONPOLYLINE()
  (setq ent (car (entsel "\nSelect a closed polyline: ")))
  (setq vertices (vlax-invoke ent 'vertices))
  (setq json_obj (list
                  (cons "type" "polyline")
                  (cons "points" (get-json-vertices vertices))
                  (cons "isClosed" t)
                  (cons "hasArc" (has-arc vertices))
                  ))
  (princ (strcat "\nJSON Object: " (json-pretty-print json_obj)))
)

(defun get-json-vertices(vertices)
  (setq json_vertices '())
  (foreach vertex vertices
    (setq vertex_type (vlax-get-property vertex 'bulge))
    (if (= vertex_type 0.0)
      (setq point_type "line")
      (setq point_type "arc")
      )
    (setq point (vlax-get-property vertex 'coordinates))
    (if (= point_type "arc")
      (setq center (vlax-get-property vertex 'startPoint))
      )
    (setq json_point (list
                      (cons "type" point_type)
                      (cons "x" (car point))
                      (cons "y" (cadr point))
                      ))
    (if (= point_type "arc")
      (setq json_point (append json_point (list
                                            (cons "center" (list
                                                           (cons "x" (car center))
                                                           (cons "y" (cadr center))
                                                           )
                                                    )
                                            (cons "radius" (abs (vlax-get-property vertex 'bulge)))
                                            (cons "start_angle" (angle-to-degrees (vlax-get-property vertex 'startPoint) center))
                                            (cons "end_angle" (angle-to-degrees (vlax-get-property vertex 'endPoint) center))
                                            ))
            )
      )
    (setq json_vertices (append json_vertices (list json_point)))
    )
  json_vertices
)

(defun has-arc(vertices)
  (setq has_arc nil)
  (foreach vertex vertices
    (setq vertex_type (vlax-get-property vertex 'bulge))
    (if (= vertex_type 0.0)
      (setq has_arc nil)
      (setq has_arc t)
      )
    )
  has_arc
)

(defun angle-to-degrees(point center)
  (setq x1 (car point))
  (setq y1 (cadr point))
  (setq x2 (car center))
  (setq y2 (cadr center))
  (setq angle (atan (/ (- y1 y2) (- x1 x2))))
  (if (< x1 x2)
    (+ angle pi)
    angle
    )
  )
```

but It not works, and I add the json-el lib like that:

```
lisp
; Load json.el library
(load "json.el")
```

Comment: Hello. I can do it for You but need some time. but by the way. tell me more about this, please. how do You get this JSON file? is that an academic project? or it's output from some external application? where we can meet data in such a format? who can be interested in this?